# How is it possible to get two different md5 hash results for the same string?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, md5sum

I am surprised by the results of the following

```
❯ md5sum <<<'hello world'
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  -
```

and

```
❯ echo -n hello world | md5sum
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3 -
```

Ideally, it should be the same, but they are not. Can someone explain?

Comment: They are not the same string - the here-string version adds a newline (equivalent to `echo` rather than `echo -n`) . See for example [Why does a bash here-string add a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char)

Comment: Replace both `md5sum` commands with `od -bc` to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the `-n` you have with `echo`:

```
md5sum <<< 'hello world'
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  -
```

vs.

```
echo 'hello world' | md5sum
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  -
```

When `-n` is used, a newline is not appended to the end of `'hello world'`.